# How to get all the elements of a column from html table and validate if a particular string exists in that list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, html-table

I have a html table with multiple rows and columns. I want to pull all the values by column id and compare with some matching string. If matches i want to enable a button on the page. 
Could you please let me know how to refer the column by id in $(document).ready function.

```
Here is the table
  <table id="data" class="table">
     <thead>
     <tr class="DataT1">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Place</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>

 <th:block th:each="it : ${data}">
   <tr>
    <td th:text="${it.id}">id</td>
    <td th:text="${it.name}">name</td>
    <td th:text="${it.place}">place</td>
   </tr>
  </th:block>
 </table>
```

Button:
    
     style="visibility:hidden">Submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//here i want to pull the place column and verify if one of the 
  places matches my input string enable submit button
 $("#submitbutton").css("visibility", "visible");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will take all information inside you `td` and search for the `string` you looking for :

But i cannot get the point that you search for a `particular string` instead of `searching for an object`.

```js
const addresses = [...document.querySelectorAll(".address")];


const serchFromList = (arr, str) => {
  return arr.map(el =>
    el = el.innerHTML
  ).filter(el => el === str)

}

console.log(serchFromList(addresses, "NY"))

/* in case you want a boolean you can use some*/

const isAddressExist = (arr, str) => {
  return arr.map(el =>
    el = el.innerHTML
  ).some(el => el === str)

}

console.log(isAddressExist(addresses, "NY"))
```

```html
<table id="data" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="DataT1">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Place</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <th>
    <tr>
      <td>4545</td>
      <td>5454</td>
      <td>65687</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aziz</td>
      <td>david</td>
      <td>paul</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='address'>NY</td>
      <td class='address'>MTL</td>
      <td class='address'>BC</td>
    </tr>
  </th>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to search for the matching string in the list of elements only from "Place" column. Could you suggest the same in jquery? I need to update the existing logic so have to use html jquery. Can I refer the column by id or class and do for each, i am not clear on how to correctly achieve this.

Comment: Done, you can just add a class and then look for the address like in  the example

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty doable with XPath if you don't want to add extra attributes to `Place` cell. Just find out the position of `Place` column and get the text from the same position of `<td>`.

```js
// Get the table node first
let node = document.getElementById('data')

// Find out position of `Place` column
let nth = document.evaluate('count(//th[text()="Place"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1', node).numberValue

// Get all the place cell by the position
let placeCells = document.evaluate(`//td[position()=${nth}]`, node)


// Get all the place names
let places = [],
    placeNode = placeCells.iterateNext()

while (placeNode) {
  places.push(placeNode.textContent)
  placeNode = placeCells.iterateNext()
}

console.log(places)
// ['NYC', 'SF', 'LA']
```

```html
<table id="data" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="DataT1">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Place</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>NYC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0002</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>SF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0003</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>LA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```